npm is not responding to any command when I run it in windows terminal
I recently installed node.js in windows 10 and was checking node and npm got installed correctly. However npm is not working at all. No error to guild me what should be fixed. I also checked environment variable and this path "C:\Program Files\nodejs" is there. terminal screenshot
environment variable screenshot
I was trying to check if the installation is done correctly or not. If not, then there should be some error. at present neither it works nor it gives any error which can be used to identify the issue. Also I tried re-installing it multiple times but even that doesn't help. I tried online forums and checked if the environment variable has been created correctly. it seems correct to me.

This is really interesting. I was also facing an issue with cmd specially with ananconda and was looking for solution for the same. The solution to that problem also solved my issue with npm. Here is the link to other thread Cmd crashes with exit code 1 after uninstalling anaconda
